# Kafka non blocking retry on consumer subscribed to multiple topics by topicPattern

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement kafka non blocking retry on consumer subscribed to multiple topics by topicPattern. I am getting this error when I try to create a retry RetryTopicConfiguration.

`No topics were provided for RetryTopicConfiguration for method dynamicConsumer in class KafkaConsumerClass`

Here dynamicConsumer is the function annotated with topicPattern.

Sample config

```
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300000);

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, StickyAssignor.class.getName() );
```

Retry config

```
 .newInstance()
 .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactoryRetry)
 .exponentialBackoff(1000, 2, 5000)
 .maxAttempts(3)
 .includeTopics(Arrays.asList("postfixtest"))
 .create(template);
```

Kafka consumer

```
@KafkaListener( topicPattern = ".*postfixtest",groupId = "edsdefd",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory4")
public void dynamicConsumer(ConsumerRecord<String,String> message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("got a message from  topic --> "+message.topic()+" - message is ->  "+message.value()+" partition" +message.partition());
}
```

Other assumptions:
Retry bean will not consume from a topic unless the parent topic has its consumer in the application context.

Comment: Please show the code for how you are configuring `RetryTopicConfiguration` and how you are using it.

Comment: I am using the above retry config only,I have added my preferred topic name in the builder.The retry config will automaticaly create retry and dlt topics for me.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "dynamic consumer"; the retry topic mechanism relies on underlying Spring Framework functionality. Provide much more information.

Comment: Dynamic consumer is just a consumer consuming  with a topicPattern instead of a single topic. I should have written multiple topic consumer by regex instead, my bad.

Comment: @GaryRussell One more question. How would you suggest to make non blocking retry bean at runtime, do you think it will be scalable. Using topicPattern is scalable by increasing consumer. I don't think the non blocking retry topics that are made automatically are scalable , atleast for topics that are created at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use non-blocking retry with `topicPattern` because the framework needs to know the topic name ahead of time so it can set up the infrastructure and retry topics.

You could use a prototype bean to create new listeners at runtime; it should work for non-blocking retry too.

See [Can i add topics to my @kafkalistener at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744775/can-i-add-topics-to-my-kafkalistener-at-runtime/68745230#68745230)

Comment: This will work for most of the cases, but I needed topic pattern like scalable solution,  by creating a listener manually, I would have to manully distribute  large number of topics created at runtime onto each server. Which won't be possible.

Comment: Currently I am making topics per client basis ,at runtime when client is onboarded, and I need to scale the servers as load increases. I don't think manually creating listener would work in my case, I would need to manually create non blocking retry pattern then.