# How can I define two or more Kafka consumers using spring boot configurations?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer

I'm new to kafka. How can I define two(or more) Kafka consumers using configuration `.properties` or `.yml`? I'm interested in using the `spring.kafka.*` application's properties and also I would like to specify two different properties for two consumers using this configuration files. For example, `consumerA` will have `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9090` and `consumerB` `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9091`. I have seen examples online using multiple `@KafkaLister` with a single `application.yml` where all the common properties of the `@KafkaLister` (consumer) beans are defined in `application.yml`. This is ok concept but in case there are more consumers and they have completely different configurations then all of the configs needs to be put in the `@KafkaListener` annotation and this will make the class long and hard to read and the .yml obsolete. Instead, I would like something like this:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer1:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9091
  kafka:
    consumer2:
      spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
      auto-offset-reset: latest
  kafka:
    consumer3:
      spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9093
      auto-offset-reset: latest
```

And also how would I then connect this configuration to the appropriate beans? I could surely define the consumer beans and then use my custom configuration files to create as many different consumers as I would like but it seems to me that I would be reinventing the wheel.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; you can't declare consumers like that, you have to use `@KafkaListener` annotations on methods or create listener containers/listeners yourself.

You can override the bootstrap servers in the listener itself...

```java
@KafkaListener(... properties="bootstrap.servers:${some.property}")
void listen(...) {

}
```

You can programmatically make multiple consumers from user properties, using the technique described here...

[Can i add topics to my @kafkalistener at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744775/can-i-add-topics-to-my-kafkalistener-at-runtime/68745230#68745230)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I understand it, in a case where I would like to have a project that has consumers(not prototype beans) that use different Kafka clusters with totally different topics and different properties, then I would not at all use the predefined `spring.kafka.*` configuration properties with the .yml or .properties, but have all the config in the `@KafkaListener` annotation or manually create all the beans required for these consumers programmatically. Do I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: Or you can define multiple consumer factories and listener container factories (beans) and reference the latter in the `containerFactory` property (which would simplify the annotation).