# dynamic kafka consumer approach, the service should listen kafka topic dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have one microservice which is currently listening to one kafka topic and doing required functionality and sending data to another topic.
But here the problem is what if topic gets changed and added multiple topics in that case wither my service needs to be modified like creating multiple consumer [one listener per topic] or my service will not work..

Is there any solution that my microservice will listen/consumer multiple topics dynamically.

Any help will be really helpful and appreciated.

I tried below approaches, not working. https://medium.com/bliblidotcom-techblog/dynamic-spring-boot-kafka-consumer-af8740f2c703  [Can i add topics to my @kafkalistener at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744775/can-i-add-topics-to-my-kafkalistener-at-runtime/68745230#68745230)

I would like to listen to multiple topics dynamically and also if some new topic added that also should be able to listen with very minimal changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your listener subscribe to a regex pattern like `service-.*`, then any new topics with prefix `service-` will be consumed by your app.